# Representing a null java.lang.Double in CORBA?

Tags: java, null, corba

Let's say I have a null java.lang.Double (object) to pass through CORBA. CORBA doesn't accept null for the double primitive type, so I'll have to map it to another double (primitive) value.

What is the best value I should use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difficult question to answer, especially if all double values are valid for whatever this variable will be representing.

The best bet would be to choose Double.MIN_VALUE or some value that will most likely not be used.

However, you need to make sure this value will also be representable in the other languages/hardware that will be interfacing with CORBA.

Comment: Okay, so that means that there is no standard way to decide this value? It is both project- and system-dependant?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I would think it depends on the project.  Really the best choices are MIN_VALUE or MAX_VALUE or 0.  However, 0 sounds like it would be a valid value, so you may not want to use it.

Comment: O won't do it. The less valid and the most improbable value is -MIN_VALUE. I think I'll use that value.

Comment: What about `Double.NaN`? This should work be semantically cleaner and work in all systems.

Answer (score 1):

CORBA value types support null; see Chapter 9 of the CORBA 3.1 spec part 1 - http://www.omg.org/spec/CORBA/3.1/Interfaces/PDF/

I think that the following IDL syntax will define a boxed value type that can represent a `double` or `null`.

```
valuetype Double double;
```

---

If you can't change the IDL and the current IDL doesn't allow you to send `null` values, then you should treat a null as an error and not try to send it.  Stealing a legitimate value (say `Double.MAX_VALUE`) from the `double` value-set to stand for a `null` is asking for problems:

- Some day there could be a need to send a `Double.MAX_VALUE` as data.
- Other existing software using this interface is likely to not know about your convention, and may process a `Double.MAX_VALUE` as its literal self.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Corba doesn't accept null for the primitive type double.

Comment: My point still stands: use a CORBA value type.  That is the ONLY way you are going to avoid losing at least one valid `double` value.

Comment: I would fully agree if I could change the IDL, but I'm forced to do with what I have and the IDL can't be changed anymore.

Comment: I agree (with your edit), I don't like using null over this, but I'm very limited in my choices. If I could rewrite this, I would simply not use double at all, but I'm forced to design over what we have.